# How to do AS3 Remoting with ColdFusion

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, coldfusion

How to do remoting with coldfusion, Can Someone help me?

I have a class

```
package 
{   
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class Remoting extends MovieClip
{
    private var rs:NetConnection;

    public function Remoting():void
    {
        call_mc.buttonMode=true;
        call_mc.useHandCursor=true;
        call_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClick);
    }

    private function OnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        rs = new NetConnection("http://localhost/amfphp/gateway/");
        var responder:Responder = new Responder(onResult, onFault);
        rs.call("HelloWorld.SayHello", responder);
    }

    private function onResult(result:Object):void
    {
        trace(result);
    }

    private function onFault(fault:Object):void
    {
        trace(fault);
    }
   }    
 }
```

An error occured

```
            Error opening URL 'http://localhost/amfphp/gateway/'
            Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetConnection.Call.Failed
at Remoting/OnClick()
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To do remoting with coldfusion, flex has an inbuilt way.

1) You need to create a Flex project specifying ColdFusion as the server

[image]

2) The coldfusion server will have, by default, all the descriptor files required for Flash remoting.

3) RemoteObjects are used to communicate with the cf components

```
<s:RemoteObject destination="ColdFusion"
    source="com.stackoverflow.testcfc"
    showBusyCursor="true"
    id="ro">
        <s:method name="myFunction"
           result="method1_resultHandler(event)">
                <s:arguments>
                    <arg1 />
                    <arg2 />
                    <!-- and so on -->
                </s:arguments>
        </s:method>
</s:RemoteObject>
```

The `source` property is the package of the cf component from the webroot.
e.g. if the webroot is `C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot` and the cfc is located in `C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\com\stackoverflow\testcfc.CFC` then the above value of `source` would be correct

4) Code to invoke the remoteObject method would be:

```
protected function sendRequest(event:FlexEvent):void {
    var op:AbstractOperation=ro.getOperation("myFunction");
    op.arguments={arg1: "someValue", arg2: 100};
    op.send();
}
```

5) The result handler would be like

```
protected function method1_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
    //return value of cffunction in event.result
    event.result;
}
```

6) The cfc would look something like

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="myFunction" access="remote" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="arg1" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="arg2" type="numeric" required="yes">
        <cfreturn arg1 & ToString(arg2)>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**EDIT**
The remoteObject I created is in mxml (for flex)
For creating a pure ActionScript remoteObject, you just need to do this:

```
var ro:RemoteObject=new RemoteObject("ColdFusion");
ro.showBusyCursor=true;
ro.source="com.stackoverflow.testcfc";
var op:AbstractOperation=new AbstractOperation(null, "myFunction");
op.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, method1_resultHandler);
if(!ro.operations) {
    ro.operations={};
}
ro.operations["myFunction"]=op;
```

Comment: You can check out http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7f9d.html for more details

Comment: @SwatiSingh the pure AS3 method is for Flash

Comment: there is only problem with this line "http://localhost/amfphp/gateway/" can u tel me whats wrong here?'

Comment: @SwatiSingh check out http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-flex-webservice-component-in.html  You will need to import the rpc.swc from your `sdkroot\framework\libs` folder

Comment: @SwatiSingh your comments are not loading, so this previous one was supposed to be before your localhost/amfphp comment

Comment: Can you access the url from your browser?

Comment: after importing both the swc there is nothing happens. i have still get the same error.

Comment: weird. Why are you creating a new class for Flash-ColdFusion remoting? the RemoteObject class is already present, use it

Comment: Are u talking about NetConnection Class?? if not, then could u tel me how can i use that class?

Comment: The `RemoteObject` class. See my answer, it's pretty straightforward